# How do I enforce MySQL to use utf8mb4 using JDBC connector without restarting the server?

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, jdbc

My current configuration is as follows:

MySQL server version: 5.7.18

Operating System: Ubuntu 14.04

JDBC Connector: 5.1.42

The problem: I can't use the configuration file in my.cnf since it will require a server restart. Since I'm using MySQL version 5.7 it supports utf8mb4 and I've updated to the latest connector for the version 5.xx series. 
I tried using init_connect as given in the documentation [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_init_connect) using the following command and using mysql user without super user priviledges:

```
SET GLOBAL init_connect="SET NAMES 'utf8mb4';SET character_set_server='utf8mb4';";
```

and setting the connection url as follows:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/xxxx?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf8&amp;characterSetResults=utf8&amp;connectionCollation=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

I also tried adding session variable to the URL as follows but it doesn't work.

```
sessionVariables=character_set_server=utf8mb4,character_set_client=utf8mb4,character_set_connection=utf8mb4,character_set_results=utf8mb4
```

Can anyone help how to figure the connection settings to allow storing using utf8mb4?

P.S: Utf-8 works fine but it does not work with utf8mb4, so can't insert  emoji's.